# One Google Sheet Appscript for multiple tabs to use dependent drop down

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets

I have created a Sheet (SheetOne) with multiple dependent drop down list which refers to the values available in tab MainSheet. Now I have created another tab SheetTwo. SheetTwo must also refer to the MainSheet for its multiple dependent drop down list values.
For tab SheetOne it is working, but to the second tab  SheetTwo it isn't. Please find the code below. Please can you help me out I am very new to JavaScript.

```js
var mainWsName = "SheetOne";
  var dropWsList = "MainSheet";
  var date = 1;
  var clientName  = 2;
  var projectID = 3;
  var taskName = 4;
  var taskDescription = 5;
  var deliveryDate = 6;
  var duration = 7;
 

  var ws = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName(mainWsName);
  var wsOptions = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName(dropWsList);
  var options = wsOptions.getRange(3, 1, wsOptions.getLastRow()-1,4).getValues();


  /*Edit functiom*/
  function onEdit(activeCell) {
    var activeCell = ws.getActiveCell();
    var val = activeCell.getValue();
    var r = activeCell.getRow();
    var c = activeCell.getColumn();
    var wsName = activeCell.getSheet().getName();

    if(wsName === mainWsName && c === clientName && r > 2){
      firstLevelValidation(val, r);
      } else if(wsName === mainWsName && c === projectID && r > 2){
        secondLevelValidation(val, r);             
      }
        else if(wsName === mainWsName && c === taskName && r > 2){
          thridLevelValidation(val, r);
        }
      }
    
    

  function firstLevelValidation(val, r){

  if(val === ""){
        ws.getRange(r, projectID).clearContent();
        ws.getRange(r, projectID).clearDataValidations();
        ws.getRange(r, taskName).clearContent();
        ws.getRange(r, taskName).clearDataValidations();  
        ws.getRange(r, taskDescription).clearContent();
        ws.getRange(r, taskDescription).clearDataValidations();
        ws.getRange(r, duration).clearContent();
        ws.getRange(r, date).clearContent();
      } else {
        ws.getRange(r, projectID).clearContent();
        ws.getRange(r, projectID).clearDataValidations();
        ws.getRange(r, taskName).clearContent();
        ws.getRange(r, taskName).clearDataValidations();  
        ws.getRange(r, taskDescription).clearContent();
        ws.getRange(r, taskDescription).clearDataValidations();
        ws.getRange(r, duration).clearContent();
        ws.getRange(r, date).clearContent();

      var filteredOptions = options.filter(function(o){ return o[0] == val });
      var listToApply = filteredOptions.map(function(o){ return o[1] });
      var cell = ws.getRange(r, projectID); 
      applyValidationToCell(listToApply,cell);

    }
  }

  function secondLevelValidation(val, r){

  if(val === ""){
        ws.getRange(r, taskName).clearContent();
        ws.getRange(r, taskName).clearDataValidations();
        ws.getRange(r, duration).clearContent();
      } else {
        ws.getRange(r, taskName).clearContent();
        ws.getRange(r, taskName).clearDataValidations();
        ws.getRange(r, duration).clearContent();
      var thirdlevelColValue = ws.getRange(r, clientName).getValue();
      var filteredOptions = options.filter(function(o){ return o[0] == thirdlevelColValue && o[1] === val });
      var listToApply = filteredOptions.map(function(o){ return o[2] });
      var cell = ws.getRange(r, taskName); 
      applyValidationToCell(listToApply,cell);
    } 
  }

  function thridLevelValidation(val, r){

  if(val === ""){
        ws.getRange(r, taskDescription).clearContent();
        ws.getRange(r, taskDescription).clearDataValidations();
        ws.getRange(r, duration).clearContent();
      } else {
        ws.getRange(r, taskDescription).clearContent();
        ws.getRange(r, taskDescription).clearDataValidations();
        ws.getRange(r, duration).clearContent();
      var fourthlevelColValue = ws.getRange(r, clientName).getValue();
      var filteredOptions = options.filter(function(o){ return o[0] == fourthlevelColValue && o[2] === val });
      var listToApply = filteredOptions.map(function(o){ return o[3] });

    } 
  }


  function applyValidationToCell(list,cell){

  var rule = SpreadsheetApp
    .newDataValidation()
    .requireValueInList(list)
    .setAllowInvalid(false)
    .build();
    
      cell.setDataValidation(rule);
  }
```

Comment: Can you provide more information on how you have it now, and If possible a sheet with the data to reproduce it?

Comment: Google Sheet LInk [https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1nUDUM4TxbHgSTnZJ1wkQE2GM3QTVwUV0G4Z-aPNf4aw/edit?usp=sharing]. 
If Client_Name is selected from the drop down list (data validation from Main sheet) its corresponding Project_Name dropdown list will pop up (which is available in Main Sheet). If Project_ID is selected its corresponding Task_Name dropdown list will pop up
Required: I have another sheet called Sheet2 which has the same columns in it which is used for entering expenses of the task. I wanted the onEdit function to execute the dropdown list operation to exec in both sheets

Comment: Basically if SheetOne is duplicated the dropdown list should work but it isn't. @Kessy . Thank you.

Comment: Hi, I have tested the sheet you shared but on sheet one it does not seem to be working either. I set another client but there is no dropdown at `Project_ID` or `Task_Name` on row 8. Can you describe a bit more the workflow by editing the question?